# Single sign on in Wordpress multisite

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, single-sign-on, sign

I have site.com, blog1.site.com , blog2.site.com and etc., installed as WP Multisite using sinlge database. How can I make same user logged in one of my sites automatically logged in when visit any other site from network?

I have tried frontend SSO plugin, but it seems not working.

Comment: did you tried simpleSAMLphp?

Comment: not yet, looks too big

Answer (score 0):

[WPMU Domain Mapping](http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/domain-mapping/) plugin can do it. It allows you to map domains to your network sites and do **single sign on** for all sites available for an user.

Pay attention that this plugin is not free.

Comment: is there any other way to implement this or any other plugin